# R: treemap categorical custom color (positive - green, negative - red)

Tags: r, treemap

I'm looking for a solution for the treemap package in R to display custom colors with a categorical variable.

```
  bing.sentiment %>%
  group_by(sentiment) %>%
  top_n(10) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  treemap(
        index="word",
        vSize="n",
        type= "categorical",
        vColor = "sentiment",
        palette = "Spectral"
        )
```

I can not find the right function. The treemap looks like this:

[image: Treemap with only red color ...]

And I would really like to have the positive fields colored in green.

Does anyone know how?